# Date format issue in Angular Moment Picker library

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, momentjs, angular-moment

I have below code in my HTML and using Angular v 1.6.3 along with angular moment picker from https://github.com/indrimuska/angular-moment-picker. I want to display calendar using format `DD-MM-YYYY`.

```
<div moment-picker="member.memberSince"
    format="DD-MM-YYYY"
    max-view="month"
    start-view="month"
    autoclose="true"
    today="true"
    ng-model="member.memberSince"
    start-date="member.memberSince | date : 'dd-MM-yyyy'">
    {{ member.memberSince | date : 'dd-MM-yyyy' || "Select a date" }}
</div>
```

I have two problems

1. When I set `member.memberSince` from JS code on page load, date is
   displayed fine e.g. `01-04-2017`. But when I select the date from
   calendar, it shows the date in undesired format e.g. `Sat Apr 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0530`.

[image]

[image]

2. If I don't set `member.memberSince`, then I
   can't see any control on page to select calendar.

[image]

How should I solve this problem?

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/fEm22LstwHnyX9V6aSQ6?p=preview)

Comment: create a plunker reproducing the issues maybe?

Comment: @tanmay Plunker added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple issues here.

Let's have a look at [docs | `angular-moment-picker`#options](https://github.com/indrimuska/angular-moment-picker#options) first,

> `moment-picker`: Two-way bindable property as **formatted datetime string**.
>
> `ng-model`: Two-way bindable property as **Moment.js object**.

Now, we should not have both set to same property for obvious reasons. If you have provided `ng-model` with same property, it seem to give precendence to that and sets the property to Moment.js object.

Next, when you have `{{memberSince | date : 'dd-MM-yyyy' || "Select a date"}}` (where `memberSince` is set to `ng-model`), which initially had a `string`/`Date` object. But when you select a date, it again becomes Moment.js object which doesn't comply to `date:'<my-dateformat>'` obviously.

Solution to your problem (if you haven't figured out yet), would be to remove `ng-model` set to the directive. And you can freely access `memberSince` from `moment-picker="memberSince"` since it would be a formatted string in your provided format i.e. `DD-MM-YYYY`.

And in HTML, you can use `{{ memberSince || "Select a date" }}` without needing to use Angular's `date` filter since `memberSince` is just a string containing your selected date in provided format.

[**working plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/bfLldyFZ6uh30W5v5AE2?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks @tanmay. I have started using angular 2 weeks back and learning many things about it. Your solution worked, although I couldn't set the date as you set in your plunker. This value was coming form backend as part of a large object, so I had to format the value on server side itself. But it worked!  Thanks again.

Comment: @Aakash I'm glad that helped a little! :)

Comment: The docs tell you to set both to the same object, which has always worked for me. AngularJS's `date` filter only works on `Date` objects, not `Moment` objects.

Answer (score 0):

The two bindings (`ng-modal`) of AngularJS are not working on `div`. 
So try something like this:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div
    moment-picker="member.datepicker"
    max-view="month"
    start-view="month"
    format="DD-MM-YYYY"
    autoclose="true"
    today="true"
   >Member Sience
  {{ member.datepicker | date:'dd-MM-yyyy' || 'Select a date' }}
</div>    

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['moment-picker']);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.member ={
        datepicker:new Date()
     }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use locale="en" with format="DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm a" , then it will be work